# Laravel auth login not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I am new to laravel, I'm working on a Laravel authentication system, and while registration works, but login doesn't do anything.

### UserController.php

```
class UserController extends Controller
{

    public function postSignUp(Request $request)
    {


        $email = $request['email'];
        $first_name = $request['first_name'];
        $password = bcrypt($request['password']);

        $user = new User;

        $user->email = $request->email;
        $user->first_name = $request->first_name;
        $user->password = bcrypt($request->password);

        $user->save();

        Auth::login($user);

        return redirect()->route('hotelier.index')->with('alert-success','Data has been saved successfully');


    }


    public function postSignIn(Request $request)
    {

        if(Auth::attempt(['email' => $request['email'], 'password' => $request['password']])){

            return redirect()->route('hotelier.index');

        }

         return redirect()->back();

    }

}
```

### Route(web.php)

```
    Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function (){

        Route::get('/', function () {
            return view('welcome');
        });

        Route::resource('hotelier','HotelierController');

            Route::post('/signup', [

            'uses'=> 'UserController@postSignUp',
            'as' =>'signup'

        ]);


        Route::post('/signin', [

            'uses'=> 'UserController@postSignIn',
            'as' =>'signin'

        ]);


    } );

   Auth::routes();

   Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

Please let me know how i can login

Thanks

Comment: **but login doesn't do anything** means ?

Comment: @zach You should use `php artisan make:auth` it will help you creating authentication scaffolding

Comment: @MayankPandeyz it's not login just refresh

Comment: @NikhilRadadiya i used php artisan make:auth but it's doesn't work

Comment: @zach If you are using that then you don't have to write auth code in `Usercontroller`

Comment: @NikhilRadadiya can you modify the code so i can try Thanks

Comment: Are you trying correct credentials. As for your code, it only redirects back when you credentials don't match

Comment: @zach Remove auth code from `Usercontroller` and check `app/Http/Controllers/Auth/` you will find `LoginController` and `RegisterControlller` that will do the job for you

Comment: @NaumanZafar yes i am trying with correct credentials

Comment: @NikhilRadadiya i didn't find the LoginController and RegisterController

Comment: @zach If you tried using `php artisan make:auth` then it should be there

Comment: @NikhilRadadiya yea it's there

Comment: `php artisan make:auth` works perfect for me. Can you try to remove and reinstall it?

Answer (score 4):

You should just you the artisan command php artisan make:auth. This will create a few things. It will create an auth folder in both your Controllers folder and view folder. It will also add to your web.php route file assuming you are using laravel 5.4. In your controller/auth directory you will find your LoginController and RegisterController. it should literally have everything you need to auth. You will need to make sure you have an email or username attribute on your User model. Also you will need to have a password attribute. From there you may want to do some customization depending on your application.

here is an example LoginController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/customer';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');

    }

    protected $username = 'email';

    public function loginNameOrEmail(Request $request)
    {
        $field = filter_var($request->input('email'), FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ? 'email_address' : 'username';

        $request->merge([$field => $request->input('email')]);

        $this->username = $field;

        return $this->login($request);

    }


    public function username()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

}
```

register controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Email;
use App\PersonName;
use App\Location;

use App\Contact;

use App\User;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */

    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'first-name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'middle-name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'last-name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'address' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'city' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'state' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:4|confirmed',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {

        $email_address = $data['email'];

        $email = new Email();

        $email->setEmail($email_address);


        $location = new Location([
            'address'   =>  $data['address'],
            'city'      =>  $data['city'],
            'state'     =>  $data['state'],
            'zipcode'   =>  $data['zip']
        ]);

        $location->save();

        $location->createCoordinates();

        $personname = new PersonName([
            'first_name'        =>  $data['first-name'],
            'last_name'         =>  $data['middle-name'],
            'middle_name'       =>  $data['last-name'],
            'preferred_name'    =>  $data['preferred-name'],
            'title'             =>  $data['title']
        ]);

        $personname->save();

        $contact = new Contact();

        $contact->email_id = $email->id;
        $contact->location_id = $location->id;
        $contact->personname_id = $personname->id;

        $contact->save();

        $user = new User();
        $user->contact_id = $contact->id;
        $user->email_address = $email_address;
        $user->setPassword($data['password']);
        $user->username = $user->getEmailUsername();
        $user->save();




        return $user;
    }
}
```

routes/web.php :

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function(){
   return view('auth.login');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@loginNameOrEmail');
//Route::get('/test')

// auth middleware //

Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {

    // Enums Route //

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::get('/dashboard', 'DashboardController@index')->name('dashboard');


Route::get('/customer', 'CustomerController@index');

Route::post('/customer', 'CustomerController@show');

Route::get('/titleEnum', 'EnumController@title');

Route::get('/genderEnum', 'EnumController@gender');

Route::get('/test', 'TestController@test');


});
```

why not user model:

```
<?php

namespace App;


use Mockery\Exception;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;

use App\Model as Model;

class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, CanResetPasswordContract
{

    use Authenticatable;
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'contact', 'username', 'email_address'
    ];

    /**
     * The column name of the "remember me" token.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $rememberTokenName = 'remember_token';

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'remember_token', 'active'
    ];

    /**
     * the attributes that should be guarded from Mass Assignment
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $guarded = [
        'created_at', 'updated_at', 'password_hash'
    ];

    /**
     * Define table to be used with this model. It defaults and assumes table names will have an s added to the end.
     *for instance App\User table by default would be users
     */
    protected $table = "user";

    /**
     * We have a non incrementing primary key
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    public $incrementing = false;

    /**
     * relationships
     */
    public function contact(){
//        return $this->hasOne(Contact::class, 'id', 'contact_id');
        return $this->hasOne(Contact::class);
    }


    public function customers(){
//        return $this->hasOne(Contact::class, 'id', 'contact_id');
        return $this->hasMany(Customer::class);
    }

    /**
     * User constructor.
     * @param array $attributes
     */
    public function __construct($attributes = array())  {
        parent::__construct($attributes); // Eloquent
        // Your construct code.

        $this->active = 1;

        return $this;
    }


    /**
     * @param $password string
     * set user password_hash
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setPassword($password){
        // TODO Password Validation
        try{
            $this->isActive();
            $this->password_hash = Hash::make($password);
            $this->save();
        } catch(\Exception $e) {
            dump($e->getMessage());
        }
        return $this;
    }


    /**
     * Returns whether or not this use is active.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isActive(){
        if($this->active) {
            return true;
        } else {
            Throw new Exception('This user is not active. Therefore you cannot change the password', 409);
        }
    }


    public function getEmailUsername(){
        $contact = Contact::getObjectById($this->contact_id);

        $email = Email::getObjectById($contact->email_id);

        return $email->username_prefix;
    }


    /**
     * @return string
     *
     * getFullName
     * returns concatenated first and last name of user.
     */
    public function getFullName(){
        return $this->first_name . ' ' . $this->last_name;
    }


    /**
     * Get the name of the unique identifier for the user.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAuthIdentifierName(){
        return $this->getKeyName();

    }

    /**
     * Get the unique identifier for the user.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getAuthIdentifier(){
        return $this->{$this->getAuthIdentifierName()};
    }

    /**
     * Get the password for the user.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAuthPassword(){
        return $this->password_hash;
    }

    /**
     * Get the token value for the "remember me" session.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getRememberToken(){
        if (! empty($this->getRememberTokenName())) {
            return $this->{$this->getRememberTokenName()};
        }
    }

    /**
     * Set the token value for the "remember me" session.
     *
     * @param  string  $value
     * @return void
     */
    public function setRememberToken($value){
        if (! empty($this->getRememberTokenName())) {
            $this->{$this->getRememberTokenName()} = $value;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get the column name for the "remember me" token.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getRememberTokenName(){
        return $this->rememberTokenName;
    }

    /**
     * Get the e-mail address where password reset links are sent.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEmailForPasswordReset(){

    }

    /**
     * Send the password reset notification.
     *
     * @param  string  $token
     * @return void
     */
    public function sendPasswordResetNotification($token){

    }

    public function validateAddress(){

    }


}
```

Answer (score 2):

May be its too late but might help others.
Have you noticed `protected $fillable = [...]` inside your `User` model that extends `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable` ? Make sure you setting all the properties for the User Model those have been defined in `protected $fillable = [...]` and then try to login using `Auth::login($user);`
My User model looks like
namespace App\Models;

```
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable {

    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    // Make sure you set these properties for the model
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'username', 'email', 'password', 'contact',];
.
.
.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your sign in controller

```
 $email = $request->input('email');
        $password = $request->input('password');
        if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel uses a property of the user instance to retrieve the user details from the database when a logged in user makes a request. This property is the value returned by the getAuthIdentifier() method of the Authenticatable object. If you are using the \App\Models\User class, then the method returns "id". So make sure the id property is set on the user instance you give to Auth::login().

Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard.php:

```
public function login(AuthenticatableContract $user, $remember = false)
    {
        $this->updateSession($user->getAuthIdentifier());

        // If the user should be permanently "remembered" by the application we will
        // queue a permanent cookie that contains the encrypted copy of the user
        // identifier. We will then decrypt this later to retrieve the users.
        if ($remember) {
            $this->ensureRememberTokenIsSet($user);

            $this->queueRecallerCookie($user);
        }

        // If we have an event dispatcher instance set we will fire an event so that
        // any listeners will hook into the authentication events and run actions
        // based on the login and logout events fired from the guard instances.
        $this->fireLoginEvent($user, $remember);

        $this->setUser($user);
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

I know this is a late answer, but I solved this issue just now using `Auth::login()` instead of using `auth()->login()`.

I think this should be the same but I don't know the main reason why it works for `Auth::login()` and not `auth()->login()`.

Comment: In my case this didn't work.